# Android 2.3 WebView goBackOrForward not working

Tags: android, android-webview, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have a WebView in my app, and based on various conditions I wish to go back to some element in the history. The obtained index is valid, although the WebView doesn't do anything (no onpagestarted) in 2.3. It works in 4.1+.

```
private Integer getBackIndex(){
    WebBackForwardList list = webView.copyBackForwardList();
    Integer backi = null;
    for(int i=list.getSize()-1;i>=0;--i){
        String url = list.getItemAtIndex(i).getUrl();
        //select the appropriate index and set to backi
    }

    return backi;
}

private void goBack(){
    Integer backi = getBackIndex();
    Assert.assertNotNull(backi);
    WebBackForwardList list = webView.copyBackForwardList();
    Log.d("web","going "+String.valueOf(backi-list.getCurrentIndex()));
    webView.goBackOrForward(backi-list.getCurrentIndex());
}
```

The log confirms that we're going back 2 indices, although nothing happens on my gingerbread device. Does this have to do anything with webView settings, or is this a bug?

Comment: Also, canGoBackOrForward returns true for the specified steps.

Comment: Same behavior, not even `goBackOrForward(-1)` works for me, but `goBack()` does. Have you found any solution?

Comment: We had no other choice than to increase min. api level to 14